# Annotation Map View (Custom Marker ) not working in swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

// My View controller Code
// AddAnnotation and MApView but I don't know the issue please upload a demo code if it is possible because I'm new in iOS

```
private func addAnnotation(coordinate coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
    let coordinatesss = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.56785, longitude: 78.54255)

    addAnnotation(coordinate: coordinates , title: "titles" , subtitle: "subtitles")

    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.56785, longitude: 78.54255)

    let identifier = "CustomAnnotation"

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "star.png")!  
    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Please show more context for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.56785, longitude: 78.54255)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate
    annotation.title = "titles"
    annotation.subtitle = "subtitles"
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```